# Raphael.js - can I use .show/.hide with fade effect?

Tags: javascript, raphael, fade

Is there a way to make element fade in or fade out using Raphael.js? My code is something like:

```
var elem = paper.circle(10, 10, 10)
elem.hide();
```

Is there an attribute to .hide() to make fade effect, something like:

```
var elem = paper.circle(10, 10, 10)
elem.hide({'duration':5000});
```

Answer (score 13):

You can animate `opacity` for fade effect

```
var elem = paper.circle(10, 10, 10);
elem.animate({ opacity : 0 }, 1000, function () { this.hide() });
```

To fadeIn,

`elem.show().animate({ opacity : 1 }, 1000);`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it without animations also: http://jsfiddle.net/3jsFe/1/

You need to take the `elem.node`

```
$(elem.node).fadeOut(2000, function() {
    $(elem.node).fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Comment: So, `elem.node` selects the xml node and then you can use jQuery over that ? +1

Comment: Yes, you can use jQuery for fade's, animations, and everything else what jQuery does. Using `elem.node` you take the node element and you can manipulate with it. You also could use (like Jashwant answered) [elem.animate](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.animate) but I prefer jQuery because I'm already used to it. :)